OpenCV finger extraction from image / liveview from camera and draw contour around finger
I would like to extract a finger from an androidx.camera.view.PreviewView in Android java.
I am using an ImageAnalysis Object to run a analyze() function on an ExecutorService.
The analyze() has a param "@NonNull ImageProxy image" from which i get the Bitmap.
This Bitmap should be processed.
I need the right sequence of opencvs algorithm's for the finger extraction.
My problem on my code is that sometimes the segmentation of the finger is not correct, because the background could have similiar colors.
My goal is it to draw a contour around the finger in the liveview (as overlay or on an ImageView).
When i take the photo i would like to have the segmented finger without background.
 imageAnalysis.setAnalyzer(executorService, new ImageAnalysis.Analyzer() {
            @Override
            public void analyze(@NonNull ImageProxy image) {

                Mat src = new Mat();
                Utils.bitmapToMat(image.toBitmap(), src);

                float zoomFactor = 1.5f;

                // Calculate new dimensions after zoom
                int newWidth = (int) (src.width() / zoomFactor);
                int newHeight = (int) (src.height() / zoomFactor);

                // Define ROI (Region of Interest) for zoom
                Rect roi = calculateRoi(src.width(), src.height(), newWidth, newHeight);

                // Crop the region of interest from the original image
                src = new Mat(src, roi);

                Mat hsv = new Mat();
                Mat bgr = new Mat();
                Mat blurredImage = new Mat();

                if (src.channels() == 1) {
                    Imgproc.cvtColor(src, bgr, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2BGR);
                } else if (src.channels() == 4) {
                    Imgproc.cvtColor(src, bgr, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2BGR);
                }

                // Apply Gaussian blur
                Imgproc.GaussianBlur(src, blurredImage, new org.opencv.core.Size(5, 5), 0);

               // Imgproc.blur(src, blurredImage, new org.opencv.core.Size(7, 7));

                Mat normalized = new Mat();
                Core.normalize(blurredImage, normalized, 0, 255, Core.NORM_MINMAX);

                Imgproc.cvtColor(normalized, hsv, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV);

                // Define the range of HSV values for skin tones
                Scalar lowerSkin = new Scalar(0, 20, 70);
                Scalar upperSkin = new Scalar(20, 255, 255);

                // Threshold the image to select only skin pixels
                Mat skinMask = new Mat();
                Core.inRange(hsv, lowerSkin, upperSkin, skinMask);

                // Apply the mask to the original image to show only the skin pixels
                Mat skin = new Mat();
                Core.bitwise_and(src, src,  skin, skinMask);

                Mat gray = new Mat();
                Imgproc.cvtColor(skin, gray, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);

                // Apply histogram equalization
                Mat histEqualized = new Mat();
                Imgproc.equalizeHist(gray, histEqualized);

                // Binarize the image using Otsu's method
                Mat binary = new Mat();
                Imgproc.threshold(histEqualized, binary, 125, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY | Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU);

              //  Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(gray, binary, 255, Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV , 15, 1);

                List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<>();
                Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
                Imgproc.findContours(binary, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

                // Find the largest contour
                double maxArea = 0;
                MatOfPoint largestContour = null;
                for (MatOfPoint contour : contours) {
                    double area = Imgproc.contourArea(contour);
                    if (area > maxArea) {
                        maxArea = area;
                        largestContour = contour;
                    }
                }

                // Create a mask for the largest contour
                Mat contourMask = Mat.zeros(src.size(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
                if (largestContour != null) {
                    Imgproc.drawContours(contourMask, Arrays.asList(largestContour), -1, new Scalar(255), Core.FILLED);
                }

                // Apply the contour mask to the original image
                Mat result = new Mat();
                Core.bitwise_and(src, src, result, contourMask);

                // Draw the largest contour on the result image
                if (largestContour != null) {
                    Imgproc.drawContours(result, Arrays.asList(largestContour), -1, new Scalar(255, 255, 255), 1);
                }

                // Convert back to Bitmap
                Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(result.cols(), result.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                Utils.matToBitmap(result, bitmap);
                final Bitmap pBitmap = rotateBitmap(bitmap,90);
                // Create a mutable copy of the bitmap

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        overlayView.setImageBitmap(pBitmap);
                    }
                });

                image.close();
            }
        });

